# Java - Method is not overridden still no error is shown

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, overriding

Have a look at the following piece of codes:

**Person.java**:

```
package hellopackage;

    public class Person implements Operations{
        String name;
        int age;
        String hairColor;
        String nationality;

        public Person(String name, int age, String hairColor, String nationality) {      
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.hairColor = hairColor;
            this.nationality = nationalityn     
        }

        @Override
        public int getAge() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return age;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public void setInfo() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }
    }
```

**Student.java**

```
package hellopackage;

public class Student extends Person implements Operations {
    String id;
    double cgpa;

    public Student(String name, int age, String hairColor, String nationality, String id, Double cgpa) {
        super(name, age, hairColor, nationality);
        this.id = id;
        this.cgpa = cgpa;
    }

    public void setId(String newIdToSet) {
        id = newIdToSet;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }

    /////a method is not overrided...still no error

}
```

And the interface..

**Operations.java**

```
package hellopackage;

public interface Operations {   
    public int getAge();
    public String getName();
    public void setInfo();
}
```

Here, what my question is, why eclipse is not showing any error even one method of the operations interface is not overridden in Student class, however error is shown at the Person class if method remains unimplemented.

**Some screenshots:**

[image]

Person:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Why would not overriding a method cause an error? The method is already _implemented_.

Comment: @BoristheSpider setInfo() was not implemented in Student class

Comment: @someuser `setInfo()` _is_ implemented in the `Student` class because it inherits from `Person`. A `Student` _is-a_ `Person`, that means it has every implementation its supertype does. Please study the Tutorial and the Java Language Specification (JLS). Also, search for "java inheritance is-a relationship" to get additional resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

Person already implemented that interface. Completely, otherwise the class would need to be abstract.

So when Student **extends** Person, it inherented all methods.

That is the *essence* of OO and polymorphism: if A extends B, then A *is a* B. There is no concept of "removing" an implementation provided by a super class. You can change the implementation via overriding, but not "undo" it.

Finally: you also want to read about the Liskov Substitution Principle - to understand how you override in a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

The **parent** class *provides* `setInfo`, in this case there is no need for the **sub-class** `Student` (which is also a `Person`) to implement it (because it will ***inherit*** the method from `Person`).